# Error characters in vimrc function

Tags: vim

I'm trying to run a function that is in my vimrc to insert dependencies in a php class.
The script must enter a parameter type hinting in the construct of my class and assign the result of this parameter to an attribute of the local class.
I'm using Linux and I found in some posts that these types of characters that are in the function are not used to Linux. But for Mac.

The function:

```
function! AddDependency()
    let dependency = input('Var Name: ')
    let namespace = input('Class Path: ')

    let segments = split(namespace, '\')
    let typehint = segments[-1]

    exec 'normal gg/construct^M:H^Mf)i, ' . typehint . ' $' . dependency . '^[/}^>O$this->^[a' . dependency . ' = $' . dependency . ';^[?{^MkOprotected $' . dependency . ';^M^[?{^MOuse ' . namespace . ';^M^['

    " Remove opening comma if there is only one dependency
    exec 'normal :%s/(, /(/g'

endfunction
```

And when I try to run this function I get:

```
Error detected while processing function AddDependency:
line   10:
E115: Missing quote: 'normal :%s/(, /(/g
E15: Invalid expression: 'normal :%s/(, /(/g
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

What is exactly this special chars?
How can I fixed this and is there some reference to learn about this chars?

Thanks advance..

Comment: Why is the quote on a newline on line 12?

Comment: Sorry... I removed this.

Comment: On a side note: you don't need `exec 'normal :%s/(, /(/g'`, just write `%s/(, /(/g` instead.

Comment: I don't recommend putting `^M` or `^[` in the document. They don't generally do what you want. I would recommend changing them to their corresponding key notation `<CR>` and `<ESC>`

Comment: Where can I find these 'dictionary'? With this corresponding keys??

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz look at `:help key-notation`

Comment: After vim in terminal? There isn't this function.  :/

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz you are supposed to type that in vim

Comment: `^M` should be entered in a special way, not as two separate characters! Press `Ctrl-V-M` (that is `Ctrl-V` and then `Ctrl-M`, but keep the `Ctrl` pressed the whole time) or `Ctrl-V` and then `Enter`.Same for `^[`, press `Ctrl-V-[` or `Ctrl-V` and then `<Esc>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
exec 'normal :%s/(, /(/g'
```

You should just do

```
:%s/(, /(/g
```

Along with fixing the `^M` and `^[` issues that should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
let segments = split(namespace, '\')
```

Looks to me as if this is missing some character after the backslash.

Comment: Nope, backslash has no special meaning inside single quotes.  See `:help expr-'`.